# Django REST Framework User Registration Privacy Issue: Looking for best practice to not show exception if user with given email exists already

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, privacy, django-rest-auth

I am suprised I have not found anything on the web regarding the following issue which I thought should be common? I may just have used the wrong search terms so I am happy to receive links with more info.

My problem is that when using ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory' I want to not give a clue to any user except the owner of an email address whether that mail is registered on my website, i. e. not show a "A user is already registered with this e-mail address." if an existing email is entered.

My assumption is that that would require for the registration endpoint to return the same response independent of whether the email exists or not. I see several possible approaches, but none seems to be a good one:

1. Use a custom exception handler to remove the exception in question from the error messages sent. That means I have to somehow identify the abovementioned exception  among all error messages sent so I can still keep the others in the response. I guess I have to identify the exception message by a string the actual error message (possibly dependent on language settings?). If there are multiple error messages I can simply remove the one in question. But if the exception is the only exception I'd have to fake the same response that would be given after successful creation of a user. That sounds fiddly and not robust to me.
2. Check uniqueness before is_valid() is called and fake a successful response. But then I won't be able to return exceptions from possible additions errors.
3. Remove the unique-contraint from the DB so that the is_valid() method does not raise an error and prevent the instance from saving in perform_create(). But I don't really want to remove that database-level protection layer.

There must be a better solution out there I hope?

Appreciate any help!
Mike

Answer (score 1):

You should change the error/validation message to be more generic, for example:

```
Email address error.
```

It is very similar situation as in login. You don't write explicitly that the email address doesn't exist or the password is too short, you just send a message:

```
Invalid email or password.
```

Additionally, you can add information that if the problem repeats please contact to system/service administrator. Then if a person contacts the administrator from his/her email problem can be fixed manually.

Solution with generating unique email address might be too complex and can bring unexpected problems. What if the user just forgot about the old account and recreate the new account, with loss of previous account's data.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a possible solution today. Seems to be a little improvised but avoids the abovementioned problems. Would be happy to hear your thoughts or suggestions.

The approach was to override the create method and if it fails to the uniqueness constraint generate a pseudo serializer instance with a modified email address that would be unique and only return errors from that pseudo instance.

Additionally, the entire create request only returns an HTTP 200 OK status, independent of whether a user was created or if a user with that mail existed.

```
#custom create method to not return "email exists" error to user if email exists
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

        try: #try if data is valid. If so, create user.
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            user = self.perform_create(serializer)
            print('User created:')
            print(user)

        except ValidationError as err: #if Validation error was returned
            email = request.data['email']
            email = get_adapter().clean_email(email)

            # check if one issue was due to existing email
            if allauth_settings.UNIQUE_EMAIL and email and email_address_exists(email):
                    # generate unique version of the mail address by appending string to local part to revalidate with unique mail address
                    provisional_email = make_email_unique(email, uniqueness_validator=email_address_exists)

                    # create fake request.data dict with unique mail address
                    provisional_request_data = request.data.copy()
                    provisional_request_data['email'] = provisional_email

                    #get new serializer with new request.data
                    provisional_serializer = self.get_serializer(data=provisional_request_data)

                    #check if data was valid if email was unique
                    try:
                        provisional_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
                        # get user who owns original email from request
                        user = get_user_from_email(request.data['email'])

                    except ValidationError as err2:
                        # else validate again, this time return any errors that may occur even with unique email
                        raise err2

            else: #if error was not (also) due to existing mail problem raise validation errrors
                raise err

        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

        # always return 200 OK if no error is shown (i. e. no 201 CREATED that could hint to an existing mail address)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
                        headers=headers)
```